# Can the Webway be used to move to a different galaxy?

Tags: warhammer-40k

The Tyranids are coming!!!!

Just a practical thought, can the Eldar Webway be used to to move away from our galaxy?

If it can't, why not?

Comment: no, because letting foul xenos touch holy terran soil is heresy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The primary reason [the Webway](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Webway) can't be used to move to another galaxy is simple: The Webway and its underlying technology is no longer maintained or in some areas, no longer exists since the [Fall of the Eldar](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Eldar). It has not been established in the franchise properties as to whether the Eldar ever traveled beyond the Galaxy in any fashion, so it is not clear as to whether the Webway spanned intergalactic distances.

- The Webway is a series of portals connected together by technology. To use the webway, one has to have an entrance and exit portal configured. Think of them as a form of stargate with each portal having a specialized identity.

[image]

> - The Webway exists as a labyrinth between the Materium and the Warp. It exists as a part of both yet existing in neither. In fact, it has been described as not being a true dimension but instead a complex network of capillaries and arteries. This forms a maze of glowing tunnels making a tapestry of hidden threads that spread between the veil of realspace and warp space. Ultimately, it is a construct that spans the dimensions. Elements of its construction includes complex psychic wards to protect it from being breached and included hyperspatial pathways.
> - Present day Eldar do not fully understand the exact shape or form of the Webway.
>   In the shattered portions of the network exist dead-ends, mazes that trap the unwary, abandoned or destroyed pathways and some even inhabited by Daemons. The doorways into these parts are sealed with runes of power in order to prevent whatever unknown horror populating them from gaining entry into a Craftworld. Knowledge of a Craftworld's placement within the Webway is a secret kept by their Seers.

- While little is known about the process used to establish the Webway, it spanned the entire galaxy. Once the Fall of the Eldar took place, the Webway became inoperative overall, though sections of it are still active for short hops.